# What are alternatives to WordNet for finding antonyms?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am looking for a resource where I can find antonyms to certain English words. WordNet would've been perfect, but it simply doesn't seem to have many antonyms in its database.

I used the `nltk` python module's WordNet implementation to find antonyms, from each lemma for each synset of the original word. But it simply doesn't provide enough words.

```py
for synset in wordnet.synsets(word):
   for lemma in synset.lemmas():
      if lemma.antonyms():
         antonyms.append(l.antonyms()[0].name())
```

For example, the only antonym to the word '**delete**' is '**recover**' according to WordNet. But in sites like https://thesaurus.com , it provides more words like '**add**',
'**restore**', etc.

Comment: intuitively, I would say that recover is the semantically best fitting antonym for delete. So why not trying to find synnonyms of the antonyms you have? Or use some semantic similarity measures (simple vector space semantics are not sufficient, they can't deal with antonyms. Maybe embeddings?)

Comment: @CLpragmatics Yeah, I'd agree that is indeed the best fit. But I want imperfect fits too. Finding synonyms to the antonyms listed by WordNet is a good idea, and I've just tried it, but it's not good enough sadly. I'm not too sure of embeddings. Wouldn't that be another challenge to solve? Since it won't be too accurate.

Comment: What English words do you need to find antonyms for? Do you have a special source or domain? This may give a a hint how to taylor a solution better to your needs.

Comment: I guess you could say its software-related domain.  @CLpragmatics

Comment: So you mean the domain of technical expressions that are related to Software? For example "file", "save", "save as", "export", "open" etc?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. @CLpragmatics

Comment: So, it would be worth a try using spaCys word2vec in order to compare semantic similarity (some weighted cosine between 300-dim vectors) on a corpus of the antonym you have from wordnet in order to find words that are similar to it. The results you could check against with wordnet again, checking whether the candidates are hyponyms or hyperonyms to the antonym. Please tell me if you tried and whether this was more successful, otherwise I'll do some more brainstorming:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the Python package [wordhoard](https://pypi.org/project/wordhoard/). You could use `wordhoard` to generate a list of antonyms. The example below is querying for antonyms for the word "delete".

```
from wordhoard import Antonyms

antonym = Antonyms('delete').find_antonyms()
print(antonym)
['accept', 'add', 'allow', 'build', 'construct', 'create', 'dirty', 'enter', 'fuse', 'include', 'insert', 'issue', 'keep', 'make', 'put in', 'record', 'restore', 'stet', 'tape', 'unbalance', 'validate', 'welcome']
```